# How to reset zoom in Aptana 3

Tags: aptana

I've discovered that Ctrl + will zoom in the text in the editor pages and Ctrl - will zoom out but I don't see a way to set the zoom to 100% or to determine what the current zoom is.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it going to:

```
window -> preferences -> aptana studio -> themes
```

and selecting the font (type and size) and that's all.